# I am trying to return all the value present in excel file but getting one first row values

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, pytest

import openpyxl

file = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\Users\ysatish\Documents\LoginData.xlsx")

sheet = file.active

Dict = {}

class Excl:

```
@staticmethod

def testCase():

    for i in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):

        for j in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):

            Dict[sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value

        return [Dict]
```

print(Excl.testCase())

Comment: Change `Dict[sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value]` to `Dict[sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value]`?

Comment: [{'Email': 'satishyadav11@gmail.com', 'Password': 937807965174, 'Testcases': 'LoginWithoutEmail'}]  ...I want to O/p in this form so i fiexd 1st row value ,

Comment: So you are saying you fixed the first row (if I understood that correctly), but expect that all rows are shown anyway? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: Yes , As Keyname should be fix ...so I fixed for every value as i will call in my Test scenario.